# Strong password validation with special characters with a RegEx in PHP

Tags: php, regex, validation, passwords

Special Characters - Allowed

Spaces - Not Allowed

Numeric Character - allowed

letter - allowed

Minimum Length of field 8

```
if (!preg_match("/([A-Za-z\S]*$){8,}/",$pass  )) {
error}
```

But there is an error!

Comment: What *is* the error? Also, why in the world are you disallowing spaces?

Comment: suppose that it does not meet the requirements because when I test aaaaaa1* it shows an error

Comment: What do you mean by special characters?

Comment: Your expression would match a zero-length string at the end of the password, hence it will match everything.

Comment: I mean üçşğ and *!-. as special character @AvinashRaj

Comment: 8 or more non-space characters will do the job.

Comment: Do non-space characters contain letter digit and these special chars?

Comment: Do you _want_ the star in your example `aaaa1*`, or do you want to rule it out?

Comment: I want to use letters(like A a ), digits, symbols like*-%.çi etc. and not use space. I accept aaaaaa1*, 12345678, aaaaaaaa,Aaa123*i

Comment: Non-whitespace characters, `\S`, is the same as `[^ \t\r\n\f]` (the `^` in a character class negates everything). So it includes everything except for a space, tab, carriage return, newline, and form feed.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for:

```
if(!preg_match("/^\S{8,}$/i", $pass)) {
    // error
}
```

---

Your current expression, `([A-Za-z\S]*$){8,}`, was a bit over-complicated and missing some key points.

First your character class, `[A-Za-z\S]`, didn't meet your requirements. `\S` is the same as `[^\s]` or `[^ \t\r\n\f]`, in other words any non-whitespace characters. This is all you need, since everything else is allowed.

Then you are repeating this character class 0+ times, followed by the end of the string. That is all fine and dandy, but you try to repeat this whole group 8+ times. All you really need to do is repeat the character class 8+ times, followed by the end of the string (and you will also want to precede this with the beginning of the string, `^`).

---

This gets you:

```
^\S{8,}$
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/vW9jT2/1)

Comment: what about special chars?

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be enough,

```
if(!preg_match("/^[^\s]{8,}$/i", $pass)) {
    // error
}
```

Comment: Have my +1 for reading the question right the first time. Leaving my answer since I spent so much time elaborating ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your expression will match anything that ends in **zero or more** instances of the characters you list; hence it will match everything. You also haven't anchored it at the front, so after fixing the zero you'd still match any password as long as it ends with a valid substring. And `\S` will match **everything** that's not a space, which doesn't seem to be what you are after.

If you want letters, digits and underscore only, use `/^\w{8,}$/`. If you want specific other characters also, e.g., `.,!+`, use `/^[\w.,!+]{8,}$/`. Etc. (Only backslash and `-` have special meaning in a character range).